# Showing and returning the number of a repeated string on a function?

Tags: python

I'm already learning Python on a online free course.
Now I have and exercise that I've been hours trying to do but.... I cannot see why it doesn't works..

The instructions are here:
Write a function called `fizz_count` that takes a list `x` as input and returns the count of the string “fizz” in that list.

For example, `fizz_count(["fizz","buzz","fizz"])` should return `2`. (Make sure your function `return`s the number instead of `print`ing it.) Check out the Hint if you need help!

Hint:
Try making a `counter` variable (for example, `count`) in your function. The counter variable could initially be set to zero. After that, you can loop through the list that you take as input and increase count by one every time an item in the list is equal to the string "fizz".

At the end, don't forget to `return` the number of `"fizz"`s!

Then here's my code:

```
x=["fizz","bear","fizz"]

def fizz_count(*x):
    count=str(0)
    for count in x:
        if x=='fizz':
            count=count+str(1)
        return count

print fizz_count(x) #It prints "fizz","bear","fizz" but the thing that I want is to                 
                    #print "2" because "fizz" is two times in that string..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your specific issue:

```
x=["fizz","bear","fizz"]

def fizz_count(x):
    count= 0
    for e in x:
        if e=='fizz':
            count = count + 1
    return count

print fizz_count(x)
```

A few issues:

1. No need of `*x` in the parameter in python
2. Use a different variable name when you are iterating through the elements.
3. `count=0` is sufficient, no need to cast it as a string
4. `if x=='fizz'`  should be `if e=='fizz'` - Check the element of the list, rather than the entire list.
5. The return statement had to be *after* the loop executes. Notice the indentation.

Ofcourse, there are better ways of achieving what you are looking for, but I shall leave it here as it seems like you are learning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! thanks for you explanation, you helped me to understand how to do "for in" and solved the problem!Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Few things about your script:

```
def fizz_count(*x)
```

This probably isn't the syntax you want here. What you're doing here is expanding the list so it takes its own argument slot. You probably want to pass it like this:

```
def fizz_count(x)
```

Next:

```
count = str(0)
```

You can simply initiate your counter like this:

```
count = 0
```

Next:

```
for count in x:
```

This now makes your `count` variable an entry in `x`, but since you expanded the list this probably isn't what you're seeing. Regardless, again, you want something like this to assign each member to a variable:

```
for item in x:
```

Next:

```
count=count+str(1)
```

Again, you don't need to convert this to a string, `count=count+1` would suffice

Finally, not sure if it's just a formatting issue, but your return statement should be outside your for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for the very constructive answer, that helped me so much! I'm learning a lot and I think now I really know how to use more easliy the "for in" and yeah, I tried without converting to a string, but it dropped me fails and I was just trying another ways to do, but now I know that that isn't necessary todo :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't really have `x=["fizz","bear","fizz"]` before the function, you should have it after as it makes more sense to have it together with the print function.
I've tested it, this should work:

```
def fizz_count(x):
 count=0
 for i in x:
  if i=='fizz':
   count+=1
 return count

x=["fizz","bear","fizz"]
print (fizz_count(x))
```

What I don't understand is why you had `count` as a string. You don't need to. Just make it an ordinary integer and the variable `i` in automatically created when I declare this for loop. Also, you shouldn't have `count=count+1` as although it still works, it isn't really the pythonic way of doing this and there's a reason the `+=` operator was built in( it does the same thing but makes your life that little bit easier)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know I had I little errors but that won't repeat again, is a good thing that `+=` I didn't know that, but know that I know, like you said, my life would be easier! :)

Comment: @RikuSoulz No problem, although hypothetically speaking I think you could still convert that count variable to a string and then change it back when wanting to add it, but like you now know it wouldn't be a very constructive way of doing things unless you're purposefully trying to make a complicated piece of code!