# Counting a specific string in the list in Python

Tags: python

I want to count 'fizz' in the list and I wrote below code and it doesn't worked. Tell me why and provide a solution. I was doing [this](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-IZ9Ra/0/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#) tutorial and I have to write code as their instruction but I am unable to do what they said or maybe I misunderstood them.

```
count = 0
def fizz_count(x):
    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count
    return count
```

If you want to check if your answer is correct then you have to check it by interpreting it [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-IZ9Ra/0/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#). Note that I am not calling my own function. Instead, their is an built in feature in Codecademy tutorial it checks function by calling function with some argument.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What wrong with `lst.count('fizz')`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I mean it is not printing the number of times the string 'fizz' is in the list x

Comment: When formatting your code, I noticed that you used tabs for indentation. Don't do this. Use four spaces for each level of indentation. (I possibly even fixed your error when I did this - mixing tabs and spaces is begging for problems in Python)

Comment: Well, what *is* it printing? Please also provide an example list that we can test your program on.

Comment: You need to declare `global count` if you want to modify `count` in an inner scope like that.  Or more sanely just ditch the global and use the return value of your function.

Comment: @Abhijit I was doing the tutorial at [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-IZ9Ra/0/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#) and I have to write code as per their instructions but I am unable to understand what they said.

Comment: @DeveshSaini: I'm not the downvoter, but it seems you haven't provided enough detail in your question. Specifically, you don't include the part of the code where you call `fizz_count()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `count` variable inside for loop, and you dont require an `else` condition

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

You can also write your function as

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return x.count('fizz')
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this below code. I made some correction in it. There were some syntactical error and some indentation errors which I fixed it. Have a look at it:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count
    return count


str1 = fizz_count(['fizzers','fizzerlss','fizz','fizz'])
print str1
```

Comment: It is printing 2 as the occurrence of `fizz` is twice.

Comment: Your code return this error:-   File "python", line 2
    count = 0
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Or you can simply do like this: `lst = ['fizz','fizz','fizzler']
print lst.count('fizz')`

Comment: the last str1 is just a variable used to store the count. I called the function `fizz_count` by passing the list and the returned value from that function is stored in the variable named str1. Then it is being printed.

Comment: Watch this links... Possible Duplicacy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591941/python-2-7-use-a-list-as-an-argument-in-a-function?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453371/showing-and-returning-the-number-of-a-repeated-string-on-a-function?rq=1

Answer (score -3):

Edit: Same with more explanation due to down votes

Considering your approach with a global variable `count` (global, because it is not within the function), you would need to do two adaptions:

- You need to make `count` available locally with the keyword `global`
- Since you use a global variable, you do not need to return it because it is available anyway

Code:

```
count = 0

def fizz_count(x):
    global count # make count available for writing in the local scope

    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count
```

Now actually using a global variable especially for such kind of tasks is not recommended, because it takes more time to load, you have to take care of the current state and stuff like that, so you rather'd introduce a local variable and pass it via the return statement as you did.

- Put `count = 0` into function

Code

```
# we put count = 0 into the function

def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0 # right here

    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count

    return count
```

Now a new `count` will be initialized to zero within the function.

Now there are two more things here:

- the `else` statement
- and the increment

Since the `else` statement is outside the loop it will be only executed if the `if` condition was never `True` during the loop. That has some use cases. But you'd put it in the loop usually. However, in your case it basically does not change anything, thats why it can be removed completely.

Well and the second point is that the increment can be written as `count += 1` which is considered more readable, because it is less clumsy and the second `count` is merged into the `+=`

Therefore finally the function could be written like so

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0 

    for string in x:
        if string == 'fizz':
            count += 1

    return count
```

Check also the reasonable solutions of the other answers

Comment: This is not a job for `global`; `count = 0` should be inside the function. Also, the `else` clause is useless.

Comment: The `else` clause is also at the wrong indentation level, though it happens to not matter.

Comment: 1. Yes, but maybe the OP wants a global `count` 2. Useless, but it's not making the code to fail (and knowing that it can be written there is somewhat helpful sometimes) @TimPietzcker @user2357112